# LNK2005: find the module which was built with /MT

Tags: c++, nmake, mapserver, lnk2005, mt

I'm trying to build C++ project (mapserver). It depends on some other projects.

When I run `nmake`, it shows many errors like this:

```
...
LIBCMTD.lib(getenv.obj) : error LNK2005: _getenv already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR90.dll)
LIBCMTD.lib(tolower.obj) : error LNK2005: _tolower already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR90.dll)
LIBCMTD.lib(fflush.obj) : error LNK2005: _fflush already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR90.dll)
MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR90.dll) : error LNK2005: __strnicmp already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(strnicmp.obj)
...
```

I know it is caused by `/MD` and `/MT` options when they differs from project to project.

I checked all project's build files and have found only one with `/MT`. I changed it to `/MD` and rebuilt it, but error remained.

How to find a library caused this error?

Thanks for all!

P.S. Project list:

```
curl-7.24.0
expat-2.0.1
freetype-2.4.8
gdal-1.9.0
gdwin32
jpeg-6b
lpng158
mapserver <-- main
postgresql-8.4.9
proj-4.7.0
regex-0.12
```

zlib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turned out very simple.

I run `dumpbin` on each library that main program uses. One of them was compiled with

```
/DEFAULTLIB:"LIBCMTD"
```

that means `/MT` option.

P.S. It is interesting, that build file didn't contain `/MT` or `/MTd` options. Instead, it included

```
<win32.mak>
```

with

```
!IFDEF NODEBUG
cvarsmt    = $(noansi) -D_MT -MT
cvars      = $(cvarsmt)
cvarsdll   = $(noansi) -D_MT -D_DLL -MD
!ELSE
cvarsmt    = $(noansi) -D_MT -MTd
cvars      = $(cvarsmt)
cvarsdll   = $(noansi) -D_MT -D_DLL -MDd
!ENDIF
```

The makefile contained

```
CFLAGS= $(cflags) $(cdebug) $(cvars) -I.
```

I replaced it with

```
CFLAGS= $(cflags) $(cdebug) $(noansi) -D_MD -MDd -I.
```

and all begun to work.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this KB

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wtdswk0(v=vs.71).aspx

Use the ignore libraries line based on the build you are trying to do.  If a library you are using needs that library, you will get a Symbol not Found for that library and you can fix it.

Also, you can use `dumpbin` to find out what a library will try to link to.